# How to correctly wait for condition variable timeout

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm working on simple cancellation mechanism. But I have found problem with waiting for timeout on condition variable.

Lets consider the sample program from:
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/wait_for/
It looks like this sample is broken. If someone would provide the data very fast then the program would go into infinite loop. To visualize it I did little modification to the sample program:

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <chrono>             // std::chrono::seconds
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable, std::cv_status
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::condition_variable cv;

int value = -1;

void compute() {
    value = 0;;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread th(compute);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    while (cv.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::seconds(1)) == std::cv_status::timeout) {
        std::cout << '.' << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "You entered: " << value << '\n';

    th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

As I can't type as fast I just set the value to 0 and execute notify_one.
On the main thread I simulate simple delay. sleep_for(1s).
Finally the program does not see the notify_one and loops infinitely.
The output is: `.....`

My question is how to implement it correctly ?
I would like to know also if the waiting was stopped by timeout.

Answer (score 5):

If the notify happens *before* the wait then it indeed gets "lost".

Most usage of CVs also require a flag of some sort which should be checked in the predicate. You already have this flag - `value`. Just use this as a predicate:

EDIT: Removed wrong code.

Note that as a separate matter you should protect the writing to `value` with your mutex or you're likely to hit UB. Which means you need to make your mutex global along with the CV/Flag.

Better way:

```
auto endTime = std::chrono::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1);
while(flag != 0)
{
   auto res = cv.wait_until(lck, endTime);
   if (res == std::cv_status::timeout)
   {
        // Add Timeout logic here
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is is possible to do it without the additional flag ? How about spurious wakeup. The timeout would be correctly readjusted ? Or it would be better to make wait_until ?

Comment: No. Spurious wakeup and wakeup that happen before the waits are the reason you need a flag of some kind. A CV doesn't store the result of previous wakeups or anything. You need to do that yourself in some kind of flag variable - which you've already got in the form of `value`.

Comment: Unfortunately wait_for with lambda returns true/false and because of that I can't evaluate if there was timeout or not (what is crucial for me)

Comment: `while (cv.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::seconds(1), [&]() {return value == 0;}) == false) {` seems to be ok. And instead of mutex, atomic<int> for value I suppose should be enough.

Comment: A better way would be an loop which checked the predicate as its condition: `while (value != 0)` and inside the loop run the wait_for and check its result - if it times out then perform whatever timeout functionality you want then `break;` else loop round some more.

Comment: And finally you probably want to - once - work out when to wait until at the beginning `auto end = std::chrono::now() + 1s;` and `wait_until` `end`. This will stop spurious timeouts resetting the wait time. See the edit.

Comment: I could not find `std::chrono::now()`, I used `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`.